# How to import component as a button in Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, next.js

I have this component with an internal link which is used on multiple pages

```
const index = ({
  as: Component,
  children,
  fullWidth,
  secondary,
  widget,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Component
      {...props}
      className={classNames(`${styles.BetTrackerCTA} btn btn-primary`, {
        [styles["BetTrackerCTA--full-width"]]: fullWidth,
        [styles["BetTrackerCTA--secondary"]]: secondary,
        [styles["BetTrackerCTA--widget"]]: widget,
      })}
    >
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
};

export default index;
```

when I try to import it as a button in the Nextjs application I get this result, it renders both the styled anchor link and the button in the background

```
<div className={`${styles.StrategyForm__submit} mt-5`}>
 <BetTrackerCTA
  as="button"
  type="submit"
  fullWidth={isMobile}
  disabled={!isFormDirty}
 >
   {t("update_strategy")}
 </BetTrackerCTA>
</div>
```

[image]

With the same code in the React application I get the desired result [image]

It looks like the prop "as" for some reason is rendering the component as a button and also the anchor inside the component, which is not happening in the regular React version

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have different styling in "the regular React version".

Your component will always render `<a>` because that's hardcoded. If you want to use `<a>` as a default component to render, you can define a default value for `as` property and you don't need nested `<a>`.

For example:

```
const Comp=({as: Component = 'a', ...rest}) => {
 return <Component {...rest}>Foobar</Component>
}
```

then following usage will render `<a>` and `<button>`:

```
      <Comp />
      <Comp as="button" />
```

[image]